# iphone facebook framework integration

Tags: iphone, facebook

Hi I'm able to successfully integrate iphone app with facebook framework.
But I need small change to be done.
Please see the URL "http://beanstalkcreative.com/screenshots/Facebook_|_Sample_Sampleson-20100407-122254.jpg", if you see the image in above URL, it shows "via MMA_app". I want to change this text to some other name. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That text is the name of your Facebook application, which you configured via the Developer page on the Facebook web site when you set up your app.  One way to change it is to simply add another app via Facebook with the new name, and reconfigure your iPhone app to use the new API Key and Secret.